# Flutter MultiProvider or ChangeNotifier doesn't response

Tags: flutter

I am using MultiProvider in the main like the following:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => ReadPreferences(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => ItemsCrud(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        initialRoute: initialPage,
        routes: {
          InitialScreen.screenId: (context) => InitialScreen(),
          HomeScreen.screenId: (context) => HomeScreen(),
          AddItemScreen.screenId: (context) => AddItemScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

But my problem is that it never read what inside ReadPreferences() class file at all, Although it reads the ItemsCrud() one normally.

My ReadPreferences() like the follwoing:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'; //To use the "ChangeNotifier"
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart'; //local store

class ReadPreferences extends ChangeNotifier {
  Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  //Constructor method
  ReadPreferences() {
    print('Please print this');

    getPreferences();
  }

  void getPreferences() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    print('print anything plz');
  }
}
```

It won't print anything at all, what am I doing wrong??

Comment: It prints to console from constructor?

Comment: No at all, and don't know why! :/

Comment: What is your `initialPage` ? Is it the same as `InitialScreen.screenId: (context) => InitialScreen()` ?

Comment: @ChrisPi yes, it's just a dynamic value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is ReadPreferences being used in any of your child widgets(Screens)? You need to use it in your child widgets, otherwise the constructor won't be called. Used like this:

```
//your child widget build method
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ReadPreferences _dummyProvider = Provider.of<ReadPreferences>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
     .....
  }
```

Comment: ooooh, you just solve it, It turns out that you have to use it in any child widgets as mentioned, many thankx ^_^

Comment: great , glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and created a test button like so that it creates an instance and fires the method in the onPressed:

```
FlatButton(
              child: Text('Provider Test'),
              onPressed: () {
                final readProvider =
                    Provider.of<ReadPreferences>(context, listen: false);
                readProvider.getPreferences();
              },
            ),
```

At first attempt I got an error :
`MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences))`

Then I ran `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` then cold restarted the app, and it works fine.

I see both print statements when I press the button.

Comment: Many thanks for your effort to test this, for my case it was that I have to call it in any child widget.